# Angular Arrays issue

Tags: angular

I have two object  arrays of same type on ts page.theyhold multiple values.The issue is when I update a value on particular index of one array it automatically update the same object value in second array.Please suggest

Comment: Post some code, maybe both of the array are referenced by themself

Answer (score 2):

You should show your code in question, but I'm guessing you created the second array by something like `Array2 = Array1` which means both `Array1`and `Array2` are references to the same array object, which would explain the described behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.map()` method to bypass this reference issue while copying arrays. As Arrays are passed as a reference so by changing one array lets say `Array2` will change the `Array1` as well.